# Mozilla Firefox download option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firefox open PDF file in a new tab. Any option to download directly? I use download in a tag. 
When we click on download button it will open in a new tab.

DOWNLOAD

Comment: Although there is a `download` attribute you can use for anchor links, support for it is patchy. In general using client-side JS to force download is not reliable. What server-side languages are you using?

Comment: It's Ruby on rails

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a header in your server that will force the file to download:

```
location ~* (.+\.pdf)$ {
    add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
}
```

Comment: how I use this for all type of file extension?

Comment: replace 'pdf' with the list of extensions you'd like to support.
(pdf|doc|exe) etc.

Comment: Is this possible In Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 comes equipped with a download attribute, and compatibility is actually pretty good.

```html
<a href="path/to/file.pdf" download="filename.pdf">Download</a>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp